# Does psexec exist by default on all Windows 7 machines?

Tags: malware, virus, windows-7

During a review of the registry editor, I found psexec and psloggedon installed upon my personal laptop. A few times, I have also observed my anti-virus restricting communication with a external entity that uses a WMI command to kill a process.

I wish to know if all Windows 7 clients are shipped with psexec and psloggedon by default, or only a person with a malicious intention could have done this?

Also, can I remove these two tools and ensure that my system is bought back to normal?

Comment: Is this a personal machine or a company machine? Have you installed admin or diagnostic tools on it? Is this a fresh install?

Comment: The machine is a personal one, and I was learning how these tools worked yesterday. And today, while doing the review, I stumbled upon this.

Comment: can you run psexec or is this just an entry in the registry?

Comment: We cannot tell you what might break if you uninstall something.

Comment: Short answer is that SysInternals tools are not installed by default but there may be valid tools that could have installed it.